# Expected to find class in file

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-3.4

I'm following the doc about the installation of Sonata Admin Bundle. I'm havong a problem during the step '[Creating an Admin](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/getting_started/creating_an_admin.html#step-3-register-the-admin-class)'.
I'm Having the following error :

> Expected to find class "AppBundle\Admin\CategoryAdmin" in file
>   "[...]/src/AppBundle/Admin/CategoryAdmin.php"
>   while importing services from resource "../../src/AppBundle/*", but it
>   was not found! Check the namespace prefix used with the resource in
>   [...]/app/config/services.yml
>   (which is being imported from
>   "[...]/app/config/config.yml").

I've created my "Category Admin class"

```
<?php


// src/Admin/CategoryAdmin.php
namespace App\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class CategoryAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper->add('name', TextType::class);
    }

    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper->add('name');
    }

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper->addIdentifier('name');
    }
}
```

and set them into the config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: fr

framework:
    #esi: ~
    translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
    secret: '%secret%'
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    router:
        resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing.yml'
        strict_requirements: ~
    form: ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    trusted_hosts: ~
    session:
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
    fragments: ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~
    php_errors:
        log: true

services:
    # ...
    admin.category:
        class: App\Admin\CategoryAdmin
        arguments: [~, App\Entity\Category, ~]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: Category }
        public: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite'
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path: '%database_path%'

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"

# config/packages/sonata_admin.yaml
sonata_block:
    blocks:
        # enable the SonataAdminBundle block
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts: [admin]
```

THe route is working so I will not post it.

My project is built like you see under the screenshot :

[Symfony Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmApG.png)

So Is there a problem with how I've built my project or I'm doing something on the config files ?
I've tried to copy/paste files names in case the problem is from a file name but It change anything. Any idea ?

Comment: I would say your namespace is incorrect for admin class.

Answer (score 0):

**Your namespace is incorrect as it seems from error and first look.**

Check following code.

```
<?php


namespace AppBundle\Admin; # CHANGE THIS LINE TO FOLLOWING!

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class CategoryAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper->add('name', TextType::class);
    }

    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper->add('name');
    }

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper->addIdentifier('name');
    }
}
```

And services

```
services:
    # ...
    admin.category:
        class: AppBundle\Admin\CategoryAdmin # fix here
        arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\Category, ~] # and here
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: Category }
        public: true
```